# How to solve "local variables references from an inner class must be final of effectively final"?

Tags: java

I have this code and I want to set a value to my `enum` variable in `actionPerformed` listener in Button, but it says:

> local variables references from an inner class must be final of effectively final

Code:

```
public class myClass {
    public enum UserChoice {
        Yes, No
    }

    public void addAction() {
        JButton btnYes = new JButton();
        UserChoice userChoice;
        btnYes.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                userChoice = 1;
                dlg.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: `userChoice` is local to `addAction` and you never use it after `addAction` is invoked.  What's the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move your variable from Method to Class:
(But, as noted in the comments, your button will not work)

```
public class myClass{
    public enum UserChoice{
        Yes, No
    }

    UserChoice userChoice;

    public void addAction(){
        JButton btnYes = new JButton();

        btnYes.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
                userChoice = UserChoice.Yes;
                dlg.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```